# Slow queries only on slaves (postgresql)

Tags: postgresql, amazon-aurora

I am using the largest size Postgresql Aurora Cluster.(Engine Version 13.3)
When only the Writer Cluster Endpoint was used, no slow queries occurred at all.
However, when Read Query is modified to use Reader Instance, Slow Query occurs.
(Sometimes queries take more than 10 seconds. And when executed in Writer, it ends in milliseconds, but in Reader, it takes more than 1 second.)

When the exact same Query is executed in the Master, the query is fast. Even if you look at the query plan, Reader and Writer are the same.

Cache hit metrics did not go down in AWS monitoring metrics.

What should be checked to determine the cause and fix it?

Highest Time Node Info

- First Query on Master

```
Node Type   Index Scan
Parent Relationship Outer
Parallel Aware  true
Scan Direction  Forward
Index Name  trace_idx09
Schema  public
Alias   trace_
Startup Cost    0.69
Total Cost  15609.54
Plan Rows   1610
Plan Width  24
Actual Startup Time 5.936
Actual Total Time   50.491
Actual Rows 2902
Actual Loops    3
Rows Removed by Index Recheck   0
Shared Hit Blocks   3917
Shared Read Blocks  396
Shared Dirtied Blocks   0
Shared Written Blocks   0
Local Hit Blocks    0
Local Read Blocks   0
Local Dirtied Blocks    0
Local Written Blocks    0
Temp Read Blocks    0
Temp Written Blocks 0
I/O Read Time   870.529
I/O Write Time  0
Workers [object Object],[object Object]
*Planner Row Estimate Factor    1.8024844720496895
*Planner Row Estimate Direction 1
*Actual Duration    151.473
*Actual Cost    15609.54
*Slowest Node (by duration) false
*Largest Node (by rows) true
*Costiest Node (by cost)    true
```

- First Query on Slave

```
Node Type   Index Scan
Parent Relationship Outer
Parallel Aware  true
Scan Direction  Forward
Index Name  trace_idx09
Schema  public
Alias   trace_
Startup Cost    0.69
Total Cost  15609.54
Plan Rows   1610
Plan Width  24
Actual Startup Time 3046.454
Actual Total Time   3387.273
Actual Rows 2902
Actual Loops    3
Rows Removed by Index Recheck   0
Shared Hit Blocks   1096
Shared Read Blocks  4191
Shared Dirtied Blocks   0
Shared Written Blocks   0
Local Hit Blocks    0
Local Read Blocks   0
Local Dirtied Blocks    0
Local Written Blocks    0
Temp Read Blocks    0
Temp Written Blocks 0
I/O Read Time   8763.617
I/O Write Time  0
Workers [object Object],[object Object]
*Planner Row Estimate Factor    1.8024844720496895
*Planner Row Estimate Direction 1
*Actual Duration    10161.819
*Actual Cost    15609.54
*Slowest Node (by duration) true
*Largest Node (by rows) true
*Costiest Node (by cost)    true
```

- Second Query on Slave

```
Node Type   Index Scan
Parent Relationship Outer
Parallel Aware  true
Scan Direction  Forward
Index Name  trace_idx09
Schema  public
Alias   trace_
Startup Cost    0.69
Total Cost  15609.54
Plan Rows   1610
Plan Width  24
Actual Startup Time 3.734
Actual Total Time   8.375
Actual Rows 2902
Actual Loops    3
Rows Removed by Index Recheck   0
Shared Hit Blocks   4039
Shared Read Blocks  2
Shared Dirtied Blocks   0
Shared Written Blocks   0
Local Hit Blocks    0
Local Read Blocks   0
Local Dirtied Blocks    0
Local Written Blocks    0
Temp Read Blocks    0
Temp Written Blocks 0
I/O Read Time   3.538
I/O Write Time  0
Workers [object Object],[object Object]
*Planner Row Estimate Factor    1.8024844720496895
*Planner Row Estimate Direction 1
*Actual Duration    25.125
*Actual Cost    15609.54
*Slowest Node (by duration) false
*Largest Node (by rows) true
*Costiest Node (by cost)    true
```

Comment: It could be many things.  Please show the `EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS)` on both master and replica.  Turn on track_io_timing first if possible.  If you immediately repeat the same query with same parameters on the replica, is the 2nd run substantially faster than the first?

Comment: @jjanes 

Thank you for answer.
As you said, the second run is much faster.
When I run `EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, VERBOSE, BUFFERS)` in Writer and Reader, the IO TIME is very different. Is there any way to solve this?

Comment: Is I/O time the only difference? How about [edit]ing the question and adding the results there?

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe
I added information about the node with the most difference in the query plan.

Comment: Sorry, but what you added is *not* the result from `EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS)`, and it doesn't contain enough information to figure out what is going on.